# Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: html, vue.js

This is for school.  It has prepackaged code.  I'm trying to run the HTML file, which is using Vue. After

```
npm run serve
```

, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

in the Debug Console of VSCode.  In the Terminal, it says:

> INFO  Starting development server...

> ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue/compiler-sfc'
> Require stack:

and it lists four .js files.

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.45"
  }
}
```

This is code in the .js file linked to my index.html file:

```
// random integer helper function
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// keyboard letter button component
Vue.component("letter-button", {
    props: ["letter", "gameOver", "twoPlayers"],
    template: "<button class='keyboard-row-letter' :id='letter' :disabled='disabled' @click='clicked()'>{{ letter }}</button>",
    data: function () {
        return {
            disabled: false
        };
    },
    // disable button on click, and send 'check' event to run check() in main vue instance
    methods: {
        clicked: function () {
            this.disabled = true;
            this.$emit("check");
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // disable all buttons on game over; re-enable all buttons on restart
        gameOver: function (newValue) {
            this.disabled = newValue;
        },
        // re-enable all buttons when a new two-player game is started
        twoPlayers: function (newValue) {
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    }
});

// main vue instance
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        // keyboard letters
        letters: [
            ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
            ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"],
            ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]
        ],
        // words to choose from
        words: [
            "BUTTERCUP",
            "TANSY",
            "PIGEON",
            "REPTILE",
            "HAWK",
            "CAPYBARA",
            "DELICATE",
            "OFFICIAL",
            "ALIMONY",
            "GRANOLA",
            "IMPERATIVE",
            "DELICIOUS",
            "ANTICIPATION",
            "APPLE",
            "BANANA",
            "BILIOUS",
            "INTESTINE",
            "AMPLIFY"
        ],

        // currentWord will be set to a random word from above list
        currentWord: "",
        // each element in this array is a letter in the word
        wordDivs: [],
        // to count the number of wrong guesses
        guesses: 0,
        gameOver: false,
        lose: false,
        twoPlayers: false,
        // will be set to the canvas element in mounted()
        canvas: "",
        // will be set to the canvas 2D context
        ctx: "",
    },

    methods: {

        // draws the gallows
        drawGallows: function (ctx) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9800";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF9800";
            ctx.beginPath();
            // left side
            ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height / 10);
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height * 0.95);
            // bottom side
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.8, this.canvas.height * 0.95);
            // top side
            ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width / 10, this.canvas.height / 10);
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 10);
            // hanging notch
            ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 5);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        },

        // fill this.wordDivs with empty strings to create the orange blanks
        makeBlanks: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                this.wordDivs.push("");
            }
        },

        // draws the appropriate part of the hanging man and/or 'game over'
        updateCanvas: function (ctx) {
            // this.drawGallows(ctx);
            // draw the head
            if (this.guesses === 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 20, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            // draw the torso
            else if (this.guesses === 1) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 40);
                ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            // draw the right leg
            else if (this.guesses === 2) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) + 30, this.canvas.height * 0.7);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            // draw the left leg
            else if (this.guesses === 3) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, this.canvas.height / 2);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.7);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            // draw the right arm
            else if (this.guesses === 4) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 55);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) + 35, (this.canvas.height / 2) + 10);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            // draw the left arm and handle game over
            else if (this.guesses === 5) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(this.canvas.width * 0.4, (this.canvas.height / 5) + 55);
                ctx.lineTo((this.canvas.width * 0.4) - 35, (this.canvas.height / 2) + 10);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

                //game over
                ctx.font = "24px Roboto, sans-serif";
                ctx.fillText("Game Over", this.canvas.width * 0.4 - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.9);
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.lose = true;

                // fill in the word with the correct answer
                for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                    Vue.set(this.wordDivs, i, this.currentWord[i]);
                }
            }
            this.guesses++
        },

        // check the chosen letter when a letter component emits 'check'
        check: function (letter) {
            if (!this.gameOver) {
                var guessCorrect = false;
                // check if the letter is in the word, if so, fill it in
                for (var i = 0; i < this.currentWord.length; i++) {
                    if (letter == this.currentWord[i]) {
                        Vue.set(this.wordDivs, i, letter);
                        guessCorrect = true;
                    }
                }

                // if there are no more blanks in the word, you win
                if (!this.wordDivs.some(function (value) { return value == "" })) {
                    this.gameOver = true;
                    this.ctx.font = "24px Roboto, sans-serif";
                    this.ctx.fillText("You Win!", this.canvas.width * 0.4 - 30, this.canvas.height * 0.9);
                }

                // if they guess wrong, draw the man
                if (!guessCorrect) {
                    this.updateCanvas(this.ctx);
                }
            }
        },

        // re-initializes the game
        restart: function () {
            this.gameOver = false;
            this.lose = false;
            this.guesses = 0;
            this.wordDivs.splice(0);
            this.drawGallows(this.ctx);
            this.makeBlanks();
        },

        // resets the game to one-player mode and chooses a new word
        onePlayer: function () {
            if (this.twoPlayers) {
                this.twoPlayers = false;
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
                this.restart();
            }
        },

        // starts two-player mode and prompts the user to enter a word
        twoPlayer: function () {
            if (!this.twoPlayers) {
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.twoPlayers = true;
                this.wordDivs.splice(0);
                try {
                    this.currentWord = prompt("Enter a word!").toUpperCase();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    this.onePlayer();
                    return;
                }
                var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
                while (!letters.test(this.currentWord)) {
                    try {
                        this.currentWord = prompt("Only letters please! Enter a word:").toUpperCase();
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        this.onePlayer();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                this.restart();
            }
        },

        // chooses a new word and resets the game when 'play again' is clicked
        playAgain: function () {
            if (this.twoPlayers) {
                try {
                    this.currentWord = prompt("Enter a word!").toUpperCase();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    this.onePlayer();
                    return;
                }
                var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
                while (!letters.test(this.currentWord)) {
                    try {
                        this.currentWord = prompt("Only letters please! Enter a word:").toUpperCase();
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        this.onePlayer();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
            }
            this.restart();
        }
    },

    // identify the canvas element and initialize it, draw the gallows, choose a word, and draw the blanks.
    mounted: function () {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("board-canvas");
        this.canvas.width = document.getElementById("board").offsetWidth;
        this.canvas.height = document.getElementById("board").offsetHeight;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        this.drawGallows(this.ctx);
        this.currentWord = this.words[randomInteger(0, this.words.length - 1)];
        this.makeBlanks();
    }
});
```

Things I did to get this far:

```
npm i
```

```
npm i vue
```

```
npm install -g serve
```

```
npm install @vue/compiler-sfc
```

```
npm install vue-loader
```

```
npm add vue@next
```

```
npm add @vue/compiler-sfc -D
```

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to use Vue as if [from a CDN](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn) but your application is using a bundler via the `vue-cli-service`. I suggest you start from scratch using [the official guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application)

Comment: Don't forget to import the `vue` dependency in your `index.html` from the CDN link. But if you try to use `vue-cli`, I'd suggest the same as @Phil, follow the official guide to generate your app :)

Comment: I tried to take out any CLI.  I put in an import on the .js file, but then I couldn't "import outside of a module".  I am not sure if that's how I was supposed to do it and I haven't seen anything on how to make an import statement in an html file.  Because I couldn't find a way to put it all together and the Pluralsight course I was taking (as part of my online schooling) was way outdated, I gave up and decided to move on.  I will have to revisit Vue later.  Thanks for trying to help!